# Keras RMSProp what is the alternative to "decay" (no longer available after Keras 2.3)

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow, keras, gan

Background: Hello, I'm creating a GAN with an RMSProp optimizer for both discriminator & generator. The generator model has half the learning rate of the discriminator (1e-4) and half the decay of the discriminator (3e-8).

Question: Keras > 2.3 no longer has the 'decay' parameter. Is the following the correct way to transfer the 'decay' parameter to Keras >2.3? I'm unsure what I would insert for "decay steps" since that wasn't a parameter before.

Keras < 2.3

```
RMSprop(lr=1e-4, decay=3e-8)
```

Keras > 2.3

```
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=1e-4,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=3e-8)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule